# Change 'Help' button url inside plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, plugin

Is it possible to change the 'help' button url inside a plugin (that I am developing) to get the documentation from my site?
I managed to add not replace, with `JToolbarHelper::help()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way of doing it.
In plugin manifest file add:

```
<help url="HELP_URL" />
```

then, in plugin language file define:

```
HELP_URL = "http://example.com"
```

Now, I have the help button, inside my plugin, with my custom url. Hope this could be usefull to someone to.